# Firebase Dynamic links only works on emulator | FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am creating a dynamic link to navigate me to a specified page, when trying it on emulator it work fine but when trying it on actual device the link only open the app

Creating the dynamic link

```
Future<void> createDynamicLink(bool short, int lecID, String lecName) async{
    setState(() {
      _isCreatingLink = true;
    });
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        uriPrefix: 'https://geneapp.page.link',
        link: Uri.parse('https://www.geneapp.com/lecture?lecID=$lecID&lecName=$lecName'),
        androidParameters: AndroidParameters(packageName: 'com.example.teams',minimumVersion: 0),
        dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
            shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short
        ),
        socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
            title: "$lecName",
            description: "new"
        )
    );
    print("https://geneapp.page.link/lecture?lecID=$lecID&lecName=$lecName");
    Uri url;
    if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl();
    }

    setState(() {
      _linkMessage = url.toString();
      _isCreatingLink = false;
    });
    print(url);
    Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: '$url'));
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    scaffoldKey.currentState?.removeCurrentSnackBar();
    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text("copied",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.grey,),
          )
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
  }
```

Handling the deep link:

```
void initDynamicLinks() async{
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
          if (deepLink != null) {
            var isLec = deepLink.pathSegments.contains('lecture');
            if(isLec){
              var lecName = deepLink.queryParameters['lecName'];
              var lecID = int.parse(deepLink.queryParameters['lecID']);
              print("initDynamicLinks | lecName : $lecName lecID : $lecID");
              await _openPDF(lecName, lecID);
            }
          }
          else
            print('its null');
        }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deeplink = data?.link;
    if(deeplink != null){
      var lecName = deeplink.queryParameters['lecName'];
      var lecID = int.parse(deeplink.queryParameters['lecID']);
      print("initDynamicLinks | lecName : $lecName lecID : $lecID");
      await _openPDF(lecName, lecID);
    }
  }

_openPDF(String lecName, int lecID) async{
    final filename = lecName;
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    if (await File('$dir/$filename').exists()){
      navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/pdf', arguments: '$dir/$filename');
    }
    else{
 
    //..
//
      navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/pdf', arguments: '$dir/$filename');
    }
  }
```

in my main build function I am setting initialRoute to a splash screen,
then in my splash screen initstate I am calling the initDynamicLinks():

Answer (score 0):

There can be various reasons for app not launching, the android device your using,  the browser used to launch the link (if a link is copy pasted in chrome they do not work), DynamicLinks setup.

You can try few things

1. encode your lecName variable in the Long URL.
2. Send the dynamic-short link over message and try to click and launch the app.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figure it out eventually, it's because firebase not available in my country. so its because I am using VPN on my laptop so on my emulator, and not using it on my mobile device.